# How can I include a php file outside of my plugin,wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, include

I am making a plugin only for myself. But I want to include a php file outside this plugin. I want to try to include wp-config.php, I also want to try to include a php file in my theme folder. How can I do that? I am using wordpress.

Comment: You should add the 'wordpress' tag to your question, so people can find this question easier.

Answer (score 0):

To use WP's core functions you should include the wp-load.php file

`require_once('wp-load.php');`

To use vars saved in the the wp config you can use the method above or just use

`require_once('wp-config.php');`

Files in your theme you should render with get_template_part if they are template files.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part